# Assign function from $rootScope to click event with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

How can I run this function with $rootScope ?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FL62y/89/)

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="parentCtrl">
      {{test}}
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl1">
          <div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
              <a href="#" ng-click="value()">show me</a>     
          </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
```

Here are my controllers:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('parentCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test = function() {
        alert("asdasd");
    }
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.value = $rootScope.test();
});
```

Alert shows up when page refresh but i want to show it after click when `ng-click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign the `test` function to `$scope.value`, just remove the `()` in the following line:

```
$scope.value = $rootScope.test;
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FL62y/92/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set $scope.value to $rootScope.test

Setting it to $rootScope.test() invokes the function and does not actually set value to a reference to the function in $rootScope.

```
$scope.value = $rootScope.test
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FL62y/91/)